# Deploying to multiple hosts using Webistrano

Tags: drush, deployment

We're using Webistrano to deploy our Drupal sites to testing and production.

The recipe we're using is as follows:

```
namespace :drupal do
  desc "symlink_files"
  task :symlink_files do
    invoke_command "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/files #{deploy_to}/current/drupal/sites/default/"
    invoke_command "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/settings.php #{deploy_to}/current/drupal/sites/default/"
  end

  desc "refresh_configuration"
  task :refresh_configuration do
    invoke_command "cd #{deploy_to}/current/drupal; drush #{drush_options} -y fr-all"
    invoke_command "cd #{deploy_to}/current/drupal; drush #{drush_options} -y updb"
    invoke_command "cd #{deploy_to}/current/drupal; drush #{drush_options} cc all"
  end
end

after 'deploy:symlink','drupal:symlink_files','drupal:refresh_configuration'
```

This method is working great for single-host deployments, but fails for multi-host deployments. The reason is that the `refresh_configuration` task will run on each host, causing all kinds of race conditions and corruption on the central database server.

My question is, can anyone suggest a way to fix the Webistrano setup to only run `refresh_configuration` task on one server only?

PS. I'm not interested in changing the deployment system to Aegir or anything else.

Comment: Do you have any error, are you sure that every host has the same architecture ?

Comment: Yes, all hosts have the same architecture. Surprisingly, there is no error that I could find in the deployment log. The recipe fails (with multiple hosts only) at the invocation of `drush updb`.

Comment: If you are interested we made a recipe than should work on multiple server http://antistatique.github.io/capdrupal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this Capistrano Wiki page](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Roles-Role), you can restrict tasks and single commands to specific `:roles` and `:only` attributes:

```
task :migrate, :roles => :db, :only => { :master => true } do
  # ...
end

task :other do
  run "migrate", :roles => :db, :only => { :master => true }
end
```

Using this, I was able to run the `refresh_configuration` task to run on a server with a specific attribute.